# Jquery slow auto scroll to page bottom 3 seconds after page load

Tags: jquery, autoscroll

Hoping someone can help me with this one...I'm building a site that needs to auto scroll slowly to the bottom of the page but give the user a few seconds to click a button to turn it off before it starts. I'm looking for the simplest way to do it, hoping to avoid any plugins.

This is what I have so far: 
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 8000);

for some reason it only goes down half way and then stops. I'm not sure how I would implement a delay and the on/off option into though. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

use a global variable :

```
var performaction=true;
```

bind the click function and add performaction=false; like that:

```
$('#YOUR LINK ID').bind('click',function(){
    performaction=false;
});
```

and add:

```
 window.setTimeout(function(){
    if  (performaction)
         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 8000);
    },3000);
```

will call the function 3 seconds after page was loaded in case button not clicked. 
i assume the problem the scroll is reaching only half the page related to when you use this line:

```
$(document).height()
```

if you use it before the page has fully loaded the DOM does not necessarily know the final height the document will have.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working for me. Uncaught ReferenceError: settimeout is not defined

Comment: sorry, try  window.setTimeout instead of just setTimeout

Comment: Oh right, I forgot to capitalize the "T" also. Works great, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my jquery skills are pretty limited...could you give me an example of how I would toggle this on and off? Basically I just have a link at the top "AUTOPLAY ON/OFF"

Comment: you want the button to switch on and off the functionality of scrolling down ?

Comment: The functionality of the auto scrolling, yes. We decided to start with it off so there will be a link at the top for the user to turn auto scroll on. It would then begin scrolling automatically and if it is turned off in the middle of the page, it would stop auto scrolling and return to manual.

Answer (score 0):

```
var performaction=true;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").bind("click",function(){
performaction=false;
});
});
window.setTimeout(function(){
if  (performaction && $(window).scrollTop() == 0)
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 70 }, 2000);
},5000);
```

This is working for me,
thanks